# why does it always give the same time?

Tags: java, swing, time, gregorian-calendar

I used the following program to get the clock.What it turned out to be is a *static clock* ? Why is it so ?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class tester {

    JFrame fr = new JFrame();
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JLabel l = new JLabel();
    Date d = new Date();
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();

    tester() {
        p.setBackground(Color.red);
        l.setVisible(true);
        p.add(l);
        fr.add(p);
        fr.setSize(200,200);
        fr.setVisible(true);
        startClockThread();
    }

    public void startClockThread() {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startClock();
            }
        };
        new Thread(r).start();
    }

    public void startClock() {
        l.setVisible(true);  
        while(true) {
            l.setText(gc.get(gc.HOUR) + ":" + gc.get(gc.MINUTE) + ":" + gc.get(gc.SECOND));
            System.out.println(gc.get(gc.SECOND));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new tester();
    } 
}
```

Comment: You should write a Thread.sleep(1000); into the infinite loop unless you want to keep your tea hot on the top of the processor.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GregorianCalendar()` Constructs a default GregorianCalendar using the *current time* in the default time zone with the default locale. [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28%29)

You can do this way.

```
while(true) {
       GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
   l.setText(gc.get(gc.HOUR) + ":" + gc.get(gc.MINUTE) + ":" + gc.get(gc.SECOND));
}
```

Now you should understand why you are getting a static clock !

Comment: I wonder if it is a good way to construct multiple objects in an infinite loop ! ?

Comment: Btw, there is another solution instead of constructing a new GregorianCalendar instance every time: gc.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeInMillis());

Comment: Better yet, instead of looping continuously [sleep()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) for 1000ms. Or use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

Comment: what are problems with this method ?

Comment: @AlistairIsrael no, you _never_ use a java.util.Timer in a Swing program - instead use a javax.swing.Timer

Answer (score 2):

You only create the GregorianCalendar once, and it never gets updated. So the date is always the same.

Answer (score 2):

there's are big problems apart from the one you have spotted:

- dont let threads run wild, they'll freeze the ui eventually
- each and every access to a Swing component *must* happen on the EDT

You can solve both easiest by using a javax.swing.Timer

```
ActionListener nextSecond = new ActionListener() {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         // get time ...
         timeLabel.setText(...);
     }
}
new Timer(1000, nextSecond).start();
```

Comment: +1 for the advantages of [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).